# Media encryption on SD Cards?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, encryption

I was wondering if it is possible to encrypt media files on an SD card? For example, we have some videos that would live on the SD card and we don't want them readable directly from the SD Card. Our app (android) however can decrypt and play the videos. Or, is it possible to encrypt or scramble the contents of our media directory on the microsd and decrypt/descramble via our app at run time?

Comment: Encrypt the data yourself.

Comment: Can I get a starting point or a hint at least?

Comment: I could only give you hints for native android programming.

Comment: Right..well, I tagged it under titanium and appcelerator..thanks anyway

Comment: I need for Native Android, if you can provide some hints.

Answer (score 2):

The titanium API does not seem to support encryption by itself. But the titanium forum did contain some JavaScript sample code that used crypto-js, so I figure you may use any JavaScript library and encrypt/decrypt each file separately.

Comment: I saw that on their Q&A page, but didn't really see how to encrypt files. Only text. I'll look more into it, thanks

Comment: In the end modern cryptography always takes bits or bytes as input. So underwater these examples must do the same. And since files consist of bytes...